# Use Avro schema generated during the process in writing operation to Avro file in Apache Beam pipeline/Java

Tags: java, oracle, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, avro

I use Apache Beam 2.49. I have to get data from Oracle database and save it in Avro file on Google Cloud Storage. I know how to get this data, schema and generate `GenericRecord` from Oracle but I have problem with use this schema during saving to Avro:

```
PCollection<GenericRecord> inputData = inputData.applay("Write to Avro", AvroIO.writeGenericRecords(SCHEMA)
                    .to(inputOptions.getOutputPath())
                    .withSuffix(".avro")
                    .withoutSharding()
                    .withCodec(CodecFactory.snappyCodec())
                    .withNumShards(1))
```

I tried to get Schema from `GenericRecord` to `PCollectionView` but I don't know how can I use it during writing:

```
PCollectionView<Schema> schemaView = parsedData.apply("Prepare Schema", Sample.any(1))
            .apply("Add schema to memory",
                    MapElements.into(TypeDescriptor.of(Schema.class))
                            .via((GenericRecord record) -> record.getSchema()))
            .apply(View.asSingleton());
```

Second thing which I tried was save schema to file and read it before saving `Schema schema  =  readSchemaFromGCS()`
and use it but then I have two ways in job so creating file wasn't waiting for saving schema.
I can't use `Wait.on(previousStep)` because `TextIO.write()` output type is `PDone`.
Anyone know how to use schema from `GenericRecord` generated during job in one pipeline?
Creating to separate pipelines doesn't satisfy me.